# What is the Dot11 frame structure of an MLME-SCAN Request?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, 802.11

Within the 802.11 specification, I stumbled upon a set of primitives that describe that the AP effectively requests that the STA scan to start roaming to another AP. These primitives are comprised of

- MLME-SCAN Request,
- MLME-SCAN Response,
- MLME-SCAN Confirm, and
- MLME-SCAN Stop.

At first glance, I was a bit thrown off by this inverse functionality but I can definitely see the use case for such a capability; where the inverse logic that I refer to is the STA is usually sending out radio resource frame requests to the AP to perform scans for nearby neighbors.

So my main question is, in what particular roaming situation would an AP emit these requests? -- Would this happen as the STA reaches a specific RSSI? Moreover, what does the frame structure for MLME scan requests even look like? Of all of the information available on MLME SCAN requests, there is little information on what the synonymous 802.11 Frame Structure makes up the scan request. -- Is it just a normal probe request that is treated differently because of the roaming context?

Comment: Can you cite the version of the spec and the specific section number you're referencing?

Comment: I am referencing https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://mentor.ieee.org/802.11/dcn/08/11-08-0046-00-000u-lb107-mlme-scanning.doc&ved=2ahUKEwjjzeKLhM_-AhWnF1kFHQysBPsQFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3Y9nCBZl_Pg9HZ36M3c2iP.  "A STA shall operate in either a Passive Scanning mode or an Active Scanning mode depending on the current value of the ScanMode parameter of the MLME-SCAN.request primitive."

Comment: @Spiff FWIW, I unfortunately don't have access to the most recent spec so this might be out of date. The link that i attached is a link to the document that I am referencing in section 11.1.3

Comment: You can get any IEEE 802 standard for free starting 6 months after ratification through the "Get IEEE 802" program. You have to register for a free account and the website UI is nonintuitive, but you can get the latest published revision of the 802.11 standard for free that way.

Comment: Sounds good, let me do that and see if I can find it in the latest spec. Thx!